# Gaussian integral from $-a$ to $a$

Tags: calculus, gaussian-integral

By using polar coordinates, one can solve Gaussian integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Why can't I use this method for $-\sqrt{t}$ to $\sqrt{t}$ where $t\ge0$ ? I'm sure there are some mistakes in the deduction. Would you please point them out?

Let $$I(t)=\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sqrt{t}}^{\sqrt{t}}e^{-x^2/2}dx \;.$$
Therefore, $$
\begin{aligned} 
I(t)^2&=\frac 1 {2\pi} \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{t}}e^{-r^2/2}rdr \\ 
&=1-e^{-t/2} \;,
\end{aligned}$$
and then
$$I(t)=\sqrt{1-e^{-t/2}} \; .$$
However, the correct answer is: $$I(t)=\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac t 2}\right) \;.$$

Comment: The error function result comes from a change of variables with $y=\frac x{\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note
$$
I(t)^2 = \frac 1 {{2\pi}}\int_{-\sqrt{t}}^{\sqrt{t}}\int_{-\sqrt{t}}^{\sqrt{t}}e^{(-x^2-y^2)/2}\;dx\;dy \;.
$$
where we inegrate on a square in the plane with side $2\sqrt{t}$.
But your attempted version
$$
\frac 1 {2\pi} \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{t}}e^{-r^2/2}r\;dr
$$
integrates on a disk in polar coordinates: center $0$, radius $\sqrt{t}$.  These are not equal.

Comment: Many thanks. The integral region is square rather than a disk.

Comment: It seems there is no difference between infinite disk and infinite square...